# Node.js and Express.JS 4 are not loading linked files when using sendFile method

Tags: node.js, express

Using Express.js 4, when I try to use sendFile in order to serve a page that has additional links to javascript files or images, the browser does not load those other assets. If I access the page using a URL it works fine, it is just when I try loading the page with the sendFile method that is the problem.

For example, here is what my code looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('client'));
var path = require('path');

app.get('/game/:gameid', function (req,res) {
   var gameID = req.params.gameid;

   if (checkGameExists(gameID)) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/client/chessBoard.html'));
}
```

I have tried a bunch of variations like:

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/client/chessBoard.html'));
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/chessBoard.html");`
res.sendFile("chessBoard.html", {root: __dirname + "/client/"});
```

I have read the Express4 API documentation on sendFile (http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile), but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am new to Node.js & Express.js so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
app.use('/assets',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public/assets')));
```

and also to make it more specific

```
app.use('/stylesheets',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public/javascripts/stylesheets')));
```

Now put your files in the public/assets folder and let's say your HTML file name is index.html.
In the index.html you can link files as **src="/assets/js/abc.js"**.

For more reference you can look into my demo [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-demo/blob/master/app.js).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the response, your demo works for urls that you type directly into the browser like `http://host/page.html`. However, I am trying to parse a url with some variables, save that state (to start a game), then serve the page. I am using the sendFile method to serve the page, and that is what is not working right for me.